# Pass custom variable to anonymous jQuery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass current iteration of foreach loop on click event, yet it returns "undefined" - but why?

```
for (var i = 0; i < __ARR_selectors.length; i++) {
    __ARR_selectors[i].click( function(e, i) {
        console.log(i); //returns undefined
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < __ARR_selectors.length; i++) {
    (function (i) {
        __ARR_selectors[i].click( function() {
            console.log(i); //returns undefined
        });
    })(i);
}
```

The problem with your code is the variable `i` is updated for each iteration of the loop, so the click event gets bound to the last value that `i` had.

To get round the issue, create an anonymous function which accepts a parameter of `i` which gets round javascript closures.

Comment: It's so stupid. If I `console.log()` it outside an click function it in the scope - wtf?

Comment: @Ultra - it's not stupid - it's design. try searching on google for articles about javascript closure - it'll make so much more sense when you understand it!